# Are only some css properties allowed to be used with Gatsby activeStyles objects?

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I'm currently styling active nav links using Gatsby Link components, Styled-Components Library and the activeStyle object.

Here the Gatsby [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) I'm referencing.

The issue I have is css properties such as `background: "red"` or `border: "2px solid green"` work, but when I use `border-bottom: 2px solid green` or `background-color: "red"` I get an error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (78:8)

76
77 const activeStyles = {
78   border-bottom: "2px solid orange",
           ^
79 };
80
```

I'm using Gatsby 2.7.1 and Styled-components 4.2.0. Up to this point, I have not had any issues with Gatsby or Styled-components. I have tried placing the object in the Link component directly too but the same issue comes up.

```
<Link to="/" activeStyle={{ border-bottom: "2px solid orange"}}>
   Home
</Link>
```

I currently doing this

```
<StyledNavLink to="/" activeStyle={activeStyles}>
  Home
</StyledNavLink>

// Styled Component
const StyledNavLink = styled(props => <Link {...props} />)`
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
`;

// Style Object passed to Gatsby Link Component
const activeStyles = {
  border-bottom: "2px solid orange", // Does not work
  border: "2px solid orange" // This does work
};
```

I'm expecting to use all CSS properties but only able to use single word CSS properties.

I don't think this is a styled-component problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style),

> The `style` attribute accepts a JavaScript object with `camelCased` properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes.

**For example**, if style attribute is `border-bottom` then in react is should be `borderBottom` and if style attribute is `border-top-left-radius` then in react it should be `borderTopLeftRadius` and so on.

You should use this,

```
const activeStyles = {
  borderBottom: "2px solid orange", // Now it will work
  border: "2px solid orange" // This does work
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

The activeStyle property seems similar to style property in react.
So you can use syntax mentioned below to solve this

```
activeStyle={{ color: "red" ; "background":"blue" }}
```

I haven't tried this in gatsby. But still I believe it should work as it works fine in react.